# Create a JSON tree in Node.Js from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, tree

I am trying for a couple of days to create a JSON tree from my MongoDB. I use the [child reference model structure](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/), where "Books" is the root node.
I am trying to achieve a JSON tree of this form:

```
[{
    title: "Books",
    children: [{
        title: "Programming",
        children: [{
            title: "Databases",
            children: [{
                title: "MongoDb"
            }, {
                title: "Postgres"
            }]
        }, {
            title: "Languages"
        }]
    }, {
        title: "Item 2"
    }, {
        title: "Item 3"
    }, {
        title: "Item 4"
    }]
}]
```

But I am really struggling to make it works. The first level (Books, Item 2/3/4) can only have 5 items, but other submenus can have an infinity.

How can I achieve the transformation form the array of data that the call to Mongo will give to this tree structure ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you struggling with? JavaScript code? MongoDB structures? You refer to data structures and code that you didn't add to your question.

Comment: Also, the tree structure you reference isn't supposed to be nested. It just lists the children of a specific tree-node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say that you have to following data (already loaded from db):

```
var data = [
  { _id: "MongoDB", children: [] },
  { _id: "Postgres", children: [] },
  { _id: "Databases", children: [ "MongoDB", "Postgres" ] },
  { _id: "Languages", children: [] },
  { _id: "Programming", children: [ "Databases", "Languages" ] },
  { _id: "Books", children: [ "Programming" ] }
];
```

Since `_id` is unique, then in first step you convert it to dictionary, where keys are ids:

```
var dct = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var doc = data[i];
    dct[doc._id] = doc;
}
```

Now you loop through `data` array one more time and set children:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var doc = data[i];
    var children = doc.children;
    var ref_children = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
        var child = dct[children[j]]; // <-- here's where you need the dictionary
        ref_children.push(child);
    }
    doc.children = ref_children;
}
```

And voila, you're done:

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

**EDIT**

If you want only roots (nodes which are not children of any other node), then first you have to find them:

```
var get_parent = function(node, docs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        var doc = docs[i];
        if (doc.children.indexOf(node) != -1) {
            return doc;
        }
    }
    return null;
};

var roots = [];
for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
    var doc = data[i];
    if (get_parent(doc, docs) === null) {
        roots.push(doc);
    }
}
JSON.stringify(roots);
```

More efficient way would be to store parents when dereferencing children (compare with the code above EDIT):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var doc = data[i];
    var children = doc.children;
    var ref_children = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
        var child = dct[children[j]]; // <-- here's where you need the dictionary
        child.has_parent = true; // <-- has a parent
        ref_children.push(child);
    }
    doc.children = ref_children;
}

var roots = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var doc = data[i];
    if (!doc.has_parent) {
        roots.push(doc);
    }
}
JSON.stringify(roots);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this last code is exactly what I needed. Except that I need to convert the _id in the field name "title" but thanks a lot ! You saved me after hours of desperation !